# Marshalling fixed Tchar[] in .netcompactFramework

Tags: .net, compact-framework, pinvoke

How can one Marshal the fixed  Tchar[] in .Net compact Framework and in.net Framework

```
typedef  struct _VXN_REGISTRATION_RESPONSE
{
       char        DID [257]; 
       TCHAR       PrimarySDCURL [257];
       TCHAR       SecondarySDCURL [257];
} VXN_REGISTRATION_RESPONSE, *LPVXN_REGISTRATION_RESPONSE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that `TCHAR` is wide. If not then you can work it out since it's the same as the `char` field.

The struct wants to be declared like this:

```
public struct LPRData
{
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 257)]
    public byte[] DID;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 257)]
    public string PrimarySDCURL;
    [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 257)]
    public string SecondarySDCURL;
}
```

The only difficult bit is that compact framework doesn't make it easy to convert from Unicode to ANSI. So to assign to DID you need:

```
string DID = ...;
LPRData data = new LPRData();
data.DID = DID.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(DID);
```